# update edit dual boot sda, sda1, sda2, sda3, sda4, sda5, sda6 install LM18 ISO

Tags: linux, partitioning, linux-mint, supergrubdisk

command steps to install Linux Mint18x on a dual boot SSD partition already installed with Window and Linux Mint 17 using the Grub Customizer Editir

What I am asking is steps to delete Linux Mint 17 partitions on sda4, sda5, sda6, and keep active partitions for (Grub Customizer 5.0.6) sda, and Windows partitions on sda1,sda2, sda3.

Information required to install Linux Mint 18 ISO and ONLY replace Linux Mint 17 partitions sda4, sda5 sda6 update Grub Customizer partition include new Linux Mint 18 menu

Need to understnd detail step by step command action analysis using LM18 ISO installation at the time when analyize sda sda1 sda2 sda3, what is the trigger used to ignore Windows sda1, sda2,sda3 and begin installation using
the older LM17 sda 4,sda5,sda6, sda partitions??
What need to be prepared to keep sda1,sda2,sda3 referenced winside sda and
then start a new LM18 installation??

Does any body understand what are the steps to install NEW LM18 over write  only the LM17 partitions on a dual boot system...  save retain sda1 sda2 sda3 windows partitions operational intact